# SP16 PowerShell - How to update field DisplayName after add in List

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powershell, 2016, spfield, display-name

I want to know what is the best way to add a field in the list and change his display name. My case adds 20 fields in the list... but the code will get big...

**This is my code(working)**

```
$SPWebHolidays = Get-SPWeb -Identity $holidaysSite  
$pathToHolidaysWeb = $SPWebHolidays.url.trim() 

$SPTemplateHolidays = $SPWebHolidays.ListTemplates["Custom List"]  
$SPListsHolidays = $SPWebHolidays.Lists  
$SPListsHolidays.Add("Holidays", "Holidays", $SPTemplateHolidays)  
$SPListHolidays = $SPWebHolidays.GetList("$pathToHolidaysWeb/Lists/Holidays")  

$SPListHolidays.Fields.Add("Area", $spFieldTypeText, $false)  
$SPListHolidays.OnQuickLaunch = $true
$SPListHolidays.Update()  

$field = $SPListHolidays.Fields.GetFieldByInternalName("Area")
$field.Title = "чинаДиаанд"
$field.Update()
```

**When i use :**

```
$firstColXml = "<Field Type='Text' DisplayName='чинаДиаанд' StaticName='Area' Name='Area' />"
$SPListHolidays.Fields.AddFieldAsXml($firstColXml, $true,
[Microsoft.SharePoint.SPAddFieldOptions]::AddFieldToDefaultView)
```

my Internal Name of field is :
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also have the option to add the fields as XML using the `AddFieldAsXml` method. When you use this, you can specify the XML string to create the field definition and it will eliminate the need to update the display name as you can specify the display name itself in the XML.

Check the below code:

```
$SPListHolidays = $SPWebHolidays.GetList("$pathToHolidaysWeb/Lists/Holidays") 

$firstColXml = "<Field Type='Text' Name='Area' StaticName='Area' DisplayName='чинаДиаанд'></Field>"

$secondColXml = "<Field Type='Text' Name='OtherColumn' StaticName='OtherColumn' DisplayName='Other Column'></Field>"

$SPListHolidays.Fields.AddFieldAsXml($firstNameColXml,$true,
[Microsoft.SharePoint.SPAddFieldOptions]::AddFieldInternalNameHint)

$SPListHolidays.Fields.AddFieldAsXml($secondColXml,$true,
[Microsoft.SharePoint.SPAddFieldOptions]::AddFieldInternalNameHint)

$SPListHolidays.OnQuickLaunch = $true
$SPListHolidays.Update()
```

Reference - [SPFieldCollection.AddFieldAsXml method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms472543.aspx)

XML that you can build - [Field Element (Field)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa979575.aspx)

Comment: see my updated question

Comment: can you try with edited answer ? have modified it to use `AddFieldInternalNameHint`

Answer (score 1):

Try to add the 20 fields in CSV file then loop for each field via `foreach` as the following

```
Import-Csv F:\fields.csv | ForEach-Object { 
    $Field= $_.Field
    $FieldDisplayName =  $_.FieldDisplayName
  // write your code

      }
```

**The CVS file format should look like**

```
Field,FieldDisplayName
Field1,FieldDisplayName1
Field2,FieldDisplayName2
Field3,FieldDisplayName3
```